# unable to view created open port on windows7 but can on mac

Tags: python, windows, macos, sockets

I have been stuck on this for a few days. When using python to open a listening socket in OSX, I am able to verify the port I'm listening on is open through [canyouseeme.org](http://www.canyouseeme.org)

Python Code

```
import socket

host = ''
port = 8072
backlog = 5
size = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.bind((host,port)) 
s.listen(backlog) 
client, address = s.accept()
while 1: 
    data = client.recv(size)
    print(data)
```

When I try and create a similar listening socket on my windows VM (running vmware 6.02), the connection times out. The steps I use in trying to connect. I had screenshots but don't have enough rep to post, hah.

1) verify actually listening:

- with CurrPorts I see Process Name: pythonw.exe, Protocol: TCP, Local Port: 8072, Local Address: 0.0.0.0, Remote Address: 0.0.0.0, State: listening ....

2) check ip address

- cmd terminal  ipconfig -all , IPv4 Address : 192.168.2.10(Preffered)

3) verify portforwarding to correct ip address

- Description: UMSM, Inbound port: 8000-9000, Type: TCP, Private IP address: 192.168.2.10, Private Port: 8000-9000
- 554 is also forwarded btw

4) port is not visible

- canyouseeme does not connect Reason: Connection timed out

I know port forwarding works because I'm able to access a different open port on Windows side 554, which an "All service Ports" on [grc.com](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?rh1dkyd2) verifies as open with all other ports < 1000 in stealth mode.

My thoughts are that I'm doing something wrong in creating the socket. Is there anything I need to do differently on windows compared to osx when opening listening sockets in python?

Thanks,

Jim

---- edit ----

now I can add pics

2.)
[image: check windows IP for port forwarding]

3.)
[image: port forwarding to windows VM]

1.)
[image: verify actually listening]

4.)
[image: could not connect]

So I know it's not a firewall because I can connect on a different windows port
[image: I can see atleast one port on windows]
[image: as shown in the grc analysis]

Also, I am able to communicate via my local network between a python server on windows and a client on OSX

Answer (score 0):

There should be no difference in how to create a listener.
Did you check, if the builtin windows firewall could block the connection (e.g. is it off?). 
And the best way to check if the listener works is to write another small application (or use telnet or netcat) which connects to it on the same machine, so that no firewall can harm.

Comment: OSX firewall is completely off, and the Windows side Home and public network location settings "turn off Windows Firewall" checked. I am able to connect talk between osx and windows VM on my local, but still unable to see the port outside my network.

Comment: Does the windows VM have its own IP (192.168.0.10) in the same network as the MAC (e.g. using bridged mode on the external interface of the MAC instead of NAT)? Are you sure, that the open port 554 is actually from the windows VM and not from the Mac itself, e.g. is the port down of the wndows VM is closed?

Comment: When I conducted this test I set the VM to bridged networking. the ipconfig command returned its own IP (192.168.0.10) and also a  different mac address. The port 554 was listed under the CurrPorts application running in windows.